# haproxy config with jwt_verify and multiple keys

Tags: haproxy

I got a haproxy.cfg file working, where the jwt signature is checked with this line:

```
  http-request deny content-type 'text/html' string 'Invalid JWT signature'  unless { http_auth_bearer,jwt_verify(txn.alg,/usr/local/etc/haproxy/cfIADN_xxCJmVkWyN-PNXEEvMUWs2r68CxtmhEDNzXU) -m int 1 }
```

cfI...XU is the kid (id of the public key as filename). I tried to use a variable for the filename to build the verification request dynamically based on the kid in the jwt header. Unfortunately it seems that variables as second parameter of jwt_verify are not allowed. The value is always taken as filename and var() will cause an exception.

Is there any way to either handle dynamic keys or at least to handle multiple keys? Or is there a way to use a JWKS url? We have keys that rotate very fast (at least daily) and multiple keys can be active at any time (due to the key rotation). I can write a small cron job that dumps the keys to files, but the selection is still a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a template for your haproxy configuration one option would be to do something like this:

Assume you have two kids key1 and key2. If you extract the kid with

```
http-request set-var(txn.kid) var(txn.bearer),jwt_header_query('$.kid')
```

you could then define two (or more) acls, one for each possible possible value of kid.

```
acl key1 var(txn.kid) -m str key1 && var(txn.bearer),jwt_verify(txn.jwt_alg,"key1.pem") 1
acl key2 var(txn.kid) -m str key2 && var(txn.bearer),jwt_verify(txn.jwt_alg,"key2.pem") 1
```

The idea here is that the key will only be verified if the first condition is true, i.e. the kid is known. From what I know `jwt_verify` won't even be called if the first part evaluates to false.

Then you could define

```
http-request deny content-type 'text/html' string 'Invalid JWT signature'  unless key1 || key2
```

I have tried to use some other approaches, using a variable to reference the key file, putting the keys in a map, but this is the only variant that was working.